# CSS Blur Effect and Background Color

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, background, blur

I have a dropdown menu that has a blur effect.  So far I have this:

```
  .transparent-header {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
        backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    }
```

### ISSUE

So far on WebKit, blur is too dark due to 0.8 alpha.
If I change that, when blur filter is not available due to an older browser, Firefox, etc, the menu would be too transparent.

### WHAT'S NEEDED

- When blur is available: blur + background alpha 0.5
- When blur is not available: background alpha 0.9

Is this possible?

Comment: Use an `@supports` rule to set your styles selectively based on browser support.

Comment: Perfect.  It worked!.  If you could post that in a reply, I can mark as answered.

Comment: Glad to help! Posted as an answer as well. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@supports` to selectively apply your styles based on browser support:

```css
    .transparent-header {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    }

    @supports (-webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(1px)) or (backdrop-filter: blur(1px))
        .transparent-header {
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
            backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
        }
    }
```